# Python tkinter 8.5 import messagebox

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox, nameerror

The following code runs fine within IDLE, but otherwise I get "NameError: global name 'messagebox' is not defined". However, if I explicitly state `from tkinter import messagebox`, it runs fine from where ever.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk 

root = Tk()
mainFrame = ttk.Frame(root)
messagebox.showinfo("My title", "My message", icon="warning", parent=mainFrame)
```

Why does IDLE not need the explicit import statement but elsewhere it is required?

Comment: IDLE is a tkinter program so It has its own import and root.  It's a bad idea programming with tkinter in IDLE. To avoid extrange behaviours is better in console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the messagebox is a separate submodule of tkinter, so simply doing a complete import from tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *
```

doesn't import messagebox

it has to be explicitly imported like so:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

in the same way that ttk has to be imported explicitly

the reason it works in idle is because idle imports messagebox for its own purposes, and because of the way idle works, its imports are accessible while working in idle

Answer (score 5):

IDLE is written in Python and uses Tkinter for the GUI, so it looks like your program is using the `import` statements that IDLE itself is using. However, you should explicitly include the `import` statement for the `messagebox` if you want to execute your program outside the IDLE process.

Answer (score 1):

`messagebox.showinfo` is defined inside `tkinter/showinfo.py` but when you use `from tkinter import *` you only import `tkinter/__init__.py` which holds the definitions of `Label`, `Entry`, `Button`, ... That is how python imports work.

When you use `from tkinter import messagebox` it looks for `messagebox` inside `tkinter/__init__.py` but it can't find it so it tries to import `tkinter/messagebox.py`

As for the IDLE anomaly, it is a bug in IDLE and I believe that it was patched.