# Python 3 executable won't close

Tags: python, tkinter, execute

When run from the Python 3 IDLE, this code works fine on the Raspberry Pi.  But if I try to run it as an executable, I can't quit the program with Ctrl+Q or clicking on the close button on the window frame.  How can I get it running as an executable?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter.messagebox

class Test:
  def __init__(self):
    root = Tk()
    root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.cmdQuit)
    root.bind_all('<Control-q>', self.eventQuit)
    Label(root, text = 'Ctrl+Q to quit').pack()
    self.root = root

  def eventQuit(self, event):
    self.cmdQuit()

  def cmdQuit(self):
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Exit","Confirm to exit"):
      self.root.destroy()

Test().root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Create app with no body ? Idle handle this. Give some geometry to root. @devenh

Comment: Are you seeing the exit confirmation box?

Comment: No, I don't see the message box.  The problem was solved by changing the way messagebox was imported.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738104/python-tkinter-8-5-import-messagebox