# Why do i need to import messagebox in python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-import

When you have this code already:

```
from tkinter import *
```

Assuming that this code means that it imports everything from the tkinter module,
why doesn't it import tkinter messagebox. I'd have to use this seperate code for it to work:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

Comment: `*` imports all names listed in `__all__`, or imports all names if `__all__` is missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python tkinter 8.5 import messagebox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738104/python-tkinter-8-5-import-messagebox)

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is a fundamental principle of importing modules in Python. And this question had already been asked and answered before [Vitalynx](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3081954/vitalynx) asked [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435163/why-do-i-need-to-import-messagebox-in-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simply the way the package was designed to work. The author of tkinter decided that importing "*" wouldn't import messagebox, or some of the other packages (`ttk` is another example)

Generally speaking, you should never do `import *` anyway.