# Why does from tkinter import * not import Tkinter's messagebox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-import

I am learning Python, and as I try some code using tkinter I hit this issue:

I import all the definitions of tkinter with the line:

```
from tkinter import *
```

Then I try to open a message box:

```
messagebox.showinfo(message='My message')
```

But when I run the program, if this line must be executed, I get the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ...
  ...
NameError: name 'messagebox' is not defined
```

If I add to the import line an explicit import for messagebox:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
```

it works, but I don't understand the reason why I have to add this import.

Comment: I haven't used tkinter before but I found this which may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24739898/14950943

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`messagebox` is a [*module*](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/tkinter), e.g. `messagebox.py`. This is not automatically imported into the namespace when you `from tkinter import *`. What *is* automatically imported is what `tkinter.__init__` [defines as `__all__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b05440c52b9814dbd47f679d47367e87855bd7b5/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L4602):

```py
__all__ = [name for name, obj in globals().items()
           if not name.startswith('_') and not isinstance(obj, types.ModuleType)
           and name not in {'wantobjects'}]
```

Notice that tkinter even explicitly excludes anything that is `types.ModuleType`, which `messagebox` falls under.

When in doubt about this type of thing, you can always [check out the CPython tkinter Python lib itself](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py).

The Python docs' [Importing * From a Package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) contain more detail.